# How to access a UIImageView from UITableViewCell in a custom function from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I try to to assign an image (which is in UIViewController) to an UIImageView ( which is in UITableViewCell) when the Camera is closing.
The problem is that I can't access my UIViewController from Cell in that function where I need it.
Where do I need to set my UIImageView to be able to access it in my function from UIViewController ?

I already tried to use a delegate method to pass my UIImageView to UIViewController and after that to call this delegate method and to assign the image. But is not working for some reasons.

Here is my code from UITableViewCell:

```
protocol DefectAndDamageCellDelegate {
    func receiveImageViewFromCell(imageView: UIImageView)
}

class DefectAndDamageCheckCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var defectImageView: UIImageView!

    // Properties
    var delegate: DefectAndDamageCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    func configCell(){
        delegate?.receiveImageViewFromCell(imageView: defectImageView)
    }
}
```

Here is my code from UIViewController:

```
extension DefectAndDamageCheckVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.defectAndDamageCell, for: indexPath) as! DefectAndDamageCheckCell
        cell.configCell()
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension DefectAndDamageCheckVC: DefectAndDamageCellDelegate{

    func receiveImageViewFromCell(imageView: UIImageView) {

        print("Image loaded")
    }
}

extension DefectAndDamageCheckVC: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    // Open camera when the user hold on a cell and choose Camera.
    func showCamera() {

        self.imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Dismiss the Camera and display the selected image into the UIImageView
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            print("Image not found!")
            return
        }

        // How can I access the imageView from my Cell here ?
        //myImageViewFromCell.image = selectedImage // issue here


        // This delegate don't work for some reasons. When I debug I can see the image on 'selectedImage' but is not assigned to my UIImageView
        receiveImageViewFromCell(imageView: UIImageView(image: selectedImage)) 
    }

}
```

Here is a GitHub small example with my issue. To access the camera you need to hold tap on cell.
https://github.com/tygruletz/sendDataFromCellToController/

Thanks !

Comment: Feels like you'r moving in circuit.. from **CellForRow**  to configCell and here you called delegates that moves back to `DefectAndDamageCheckVC.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point is to have some data source array

```
var images = [UIImage]()
```

which declares how many cells your table view has

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}
```

Then with this data source you can say something like, if this is cell at this `IndexPath` set this image. For this purpose you can easily access `UIImageView` of certain cell in `cellForRowAt`, you don't need delegate protocol

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.defectAndDamageCell, for: indexPath) as! DefectAndDamageCheckCell
    cell.defectImageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

So, when image is picked by `UIImagePickerController`, change data source for your table view (append this new image) and then insert new row to table view

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("Image not found!")
        return
    }

    images.append(selectedImage)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: images.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: I implement what you told me but is crushing now on this line with this error:
 cell.defectImageView.image = images[indexPath.row] // Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: @Flo don't forget to change `numberOfRowsInSection` data source method to return number of elements inside `images` array

Comment: I did and is still crashing in the same place.

Comment: @Flo when do you get this error? When you start your app?

Comment: Yes Robert. When I start my app is crashing.

Comment: is possible to have a solution without to depend my whole app on images.count ? Because there I have a lot of components in my cell and I open the camera with TapGesture on cell.

Comment: @Flo actually, you can have array of optional images which says [UIImage(), nil, UIImage(), nil, nil, etc...] or you can have default images, or you can have custom model with image property, ...

Comment: Sorry because I bother you but I created a GitHub small example with my issue which reflect exactly my issue on my project. Do you think you can take a look on it ? Thanks.